# What factors are needed to be taken into account when building a vending machine?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I'm a software engineer whose main concentration has been data science with some minor electrical engineering on the side.

I want to delve into some mechanical engineering by building a proper mini vending machine but am having trouble knowing which materials to use as a consequence of not knowing where to find good documentation.

Is corrosion resistance important for a vending machine? Do I use aluminum or steel? What factors would I need to take into account if it were a 2 meters tall, 1 meter deep machine, for example? Or another size?

Apologies if this is mistagged.

Thank you.

Comment: How complex of a vending machine?  A full size commercial vending machine is obviously something that has been developed over a long period of time by a lot of people.  Is it for personal use or does it have to be safe enough to be in the public as well?

Comment: What kind of vending machine? Cigarettes, gum balls, beverages, snacks?

Comment: The material depends a lot on how many machines you want to make. If it is just one, aluminum is a very good material. Easy to mill and very corrosion resistant. For the case, steel is probably the best

Comment: Well, let's say public use? Otherwise, I could just build a cardboard cutout to house the bill acceptor and other components. Let's say snacks. And yes just one.

Comment: I would suggest looking at patents to get some ideas, then come here with more specific engineering questions. As it stands this question is really broad

Comment: Awesome, that's the answer I was looking for. It wouldn't have crossed my mind to look at patents. I realize it's  broad but that's why I came here first; to know where to go.

Comment: I think the OP clearly detailed the question in its body, only its title can seem too broad. Thus I suggest to vote for "leave open".

Comment: Sounds like you need to better define the functional requirements, the rest will become obvious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you start thinking about technical solutions like materials and mechanisms you really need to come up with a reasonably detailed design specification, this should address the problem in terms of what you want to achieve rather than how you will achieve it. This also involves precisely setting out the problem that you want to solve.

Clearly one crucial element will be the product you are dispensing for example :

- Shelf life : how will you ensure efficient stock rotation ?
- Volume : how much of the product should the machine hold ?
- Storage requirements : temperature, humidity etc
- Is the product individually packaged or does it need to be dispensed into containers at the point of delivery ? Does it have specific handling requirements ?
- How many different types of product will the machine stock ?

Other important elements might include :

- Security
- Safety
- Branding and aesthetic appearance
- How payment will be taken
- User interface
- Reliability